# Altium: How to hide silkscreen designator for specific components

Tags: altium

In Altium, how can I hide the component designator for a specific component, without hiding the designators for all components?

Comment: I have a feeling that I'm missing something simple. When I search online for the answer to this question, I only find instructions for hiding *all* component designators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the component you want to hide the designator of.

On the properties tab, near the Designator field, click the "eye" icon.

Shown:

[image]

Hidden:

[image]